# Codeigniter session not working in other functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hi i have this new type of problem it is that my codeignitor sessions not work in other functions in controller

for example my login3 function

```
\\Data is coming from here fine
foreach($query as $row)
{

 $name = $row->name;
 $id = $row->id;
$dmail = $row->email;

}

 if(isset($dmail))
{



  $arr = array();


 $arr['name'] = $name;
 $arr['id'] = $id;
 $arr['email'] = $email;


 $this->session->set_userdata("facebooker",$arr);

 $this->load->model('Gift');



$this->load->library('session');

$der = $this->session->userdata("facebooker");


 $arrr = array();



 $arrr['unamer'] = $der['name'];

 $arrr['ids'] = $der['id'];
 $arrr['email'] = $der['email'];

//After loading the views all data shows fine

$this->load->view("gifttoday/header",$arrr);
$this->load->view("gifttoday/welcome",$arrr);

 }
```

But when i call the same session in this function but in same controller it shows no data

```
function profileselect()
{
$this->load->model('Gift');

 $var =array();

 $this->load->library('session');
 // Here i call this session but no data
  $mer = $this->session->userdata("facebooker");
 // When i print all the values of $mer it shows empty array 
 var_dump($mer);
/**
$this->load->view("gifttoday/header",$arrr);
$this->load->view("gifttoday/profilev",$arrr);
**/
  }
```

I have searched this problem and my people are having this problem with codeignitor sessions but non of the fixes worked for me can any body help me with this.

Comment: its because youre setting the session before loading the session library, you must load first the library before setting the session.

Comment: load session library in constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is to load session Library in constructor

```
public function __construct() 
    {

      $this->load->library('session');
}
```

Or enable session Library in `config.php`

Comment: Thanks man know i just opened my seesion library in the construnctor once and all started working

Comment: enable it inside config.php or inside autoload.php?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the library after setting the session data which probably overwrites it (in case you already had the session library loaded in the first place):

So this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata("facebooker",$arr);
$this->load->model('Gift');

$this->load->library('session');
```

Should be this:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata("facebooker",$arr);
$this->load->model('Gift');
```

But, if you intend to use the session library in several places in your app, it's a better idea to autoload it...

Edit this line in file **application/config/autoload.php**

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session',...);`

and then just avoid loading it manually when needed.

Comment: Thanks man know i just opened my seesion library in the construnctor once and all started working

Comment: Thanks man know i just opened my seesion library in the construnctor once and all started working